# Django query works in shell, but jinja wont recognize in template

Tags: python, html, django, jinja2

Right now I can run a query in the python shell and have it return True, but when trying to replicate in my html jinja template, I can't get it return the same True result.

I have a query that puts a Post.object.get(id=1) as a variable.

```
P1=Post.objects.get(id=1)
```

then ran:

```
P1.liked_by.all()
```

which does return results:

```
<QuerySet [<User: User object(10)>, <User: User object (12), <User: User 
object (13)>]>
```

then I put a variable in for a User found in that query:

```
JV= User.objects.get(id=10)
```

This user id is found in the P1.liked_by.all() query, so now when I test to see if it is found.

```
JV in P1.liked_by.all()
True
```

Now when I try to access this in my **html jinja template**. I can not get it to check against it and return true. Even though I can print the values on the page.

Here is my Views.py:

```
def topic(request,topic_id):
if not 'u_id' in request.session:
    return redirect('/')
print(request.session)

context={
    "topic":Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id),
    "user":User.objects.get(id=request.session["u_id"]),
    "posts":Post.objects.filter(topic=topic_id),
}
return render(request, 'topic.html', context)
```

Here is my HTML:

```
{% for post in posts %}
        <div class="cast-content">
            <h3>Casting submit by <u>{{post.user.user_name}}!</u></h3>
            <p>number of likes:{{post.liked_by.count}}</p>
            <p>post id:{{post.id}}</p>
            <p>user_id in session= {{user.id}}</p>
            <p>liked by:{{post.liked_by.all}}</p>
            <img src="{{post.image.url}}" class="post-pix" alt="...">
            <br>
            <p>post liked_by values: {{post.liked_by.values}}</p>


            {% if user.id in post.liked_by.all %}

                <a href="/like-remove/{{topic.id}}/{{post.id}}">Un-Like</a>


            {% else %}
                <form action="/add-like" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="{{post.id}}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="topic" value="{{topic.id}}">
                    <input type="submit" value="Like">
                </form>
            {% endif %}

            {% if user.id == post.user.id %}

            <a href="/post-remove/{{topic.id}}/{{post.id}}">Remove</a>


            {% endif %}

        </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

I can not figure out why I can print the values in the template but when I run the {% if %} statement to check if it exists in the table It can't find it therefore defaulting into the {% else %} statement every single time.  Any help at all is so greatly appreciated!

Comment: But why are you suddenly referring to `user.id` rather than just `user`?

Comment: Plus, this is Django template language, not Jinja.

Comment: WELL THAT WORKED!!!!!
Thank you @DanielRoseman, now i have to figure out how to credit you, i'm new to Stack overflow.